# Product of two nonmeager sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, baire-category

Let $A, B\subseteq \mathbb R$. Suppose both $A, B$ are non meager sets. Is is true that $A\times B\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is non-meager?
What if at leats one of them is co-meager?

Comment: Yes, look up the Kuratowski-Ulam theorem